# Get thumbprint of currently imported certificate

Tags: x509certificate, powershell-4.0

I need to import a certificate and get its thumbprint. I tried cmdlet + pipe like this:

`Import-Certificate <parameters> | Get-ItemProperty -Name Thumbprint`

But I get error *Get-ItemProperty : Cannot use interface. The IPropertyCmdletProvider interface is not supported by this provider.* I get this error any time I try to use the Get-ItemProperty cmdlet.

And I don't know how would I use this further in the script, even if it went through. Because if I put a variable definition in front of it, like `$Thumbprint = Import-Certificate <parameters> | Get-ItemProperty -Name Thumbprint`, I suppose it wouldn't really import the certificate to the store, but just store it to the variable, right?

I need to use PowerShell v4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, you want to use `Select-Object` instead of `Get-ItemProperty`:

```
Import-Certificate <parameters> | Select-Object Thumbprint
```

But as you guessed, `Import-Certificate` imports certificate to local certificate store. If you want to view certificate without installing it anywhere, then use this syntax:

```
New-Object Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $path | Select-Object Thumbprint
```

Comment: I need to install the certificate, get its thumbprint and store the thumbprint to a variable. Then I need to do another operation with the variable, but for that I'll create another question.

Comment: Just tried to add `$Thumbprint = ` to the code and it did import the certificate as well, so mission accomplished for this question :-)